# Upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 20.04

Yes, I'm working on **14.04 LTS**... And if I could have another year for updates I won't change. Despite having used Ubuntu since 10.XX, this is the first time I need to upgrade (not install from scratch).

And, I'm asking if it easy to upgrade directly to the **20.04 LTS** (I have read a lot of good things) or it will be a problem (of any type) and it's best to move first to 16.04 or 18.04...

I'm not asking for an install guideline. I'm asking for the community knowledge about upgrading Ubuntu. Maybe some packages will cause tremendous hardships or something like that.

Comment: Most likely the direct upgrade won't be successful no matter what you'll be advised here. It is not supported. Even upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 (unity to gnome) was very hard and in many cases failed badly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu has made many changes from Trusty Tahr (14.04) to Focal Fossa (20.04).

So, I would suggest backing up all your data (you can use deja dup) and then installing focal using [installation media](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/) created from the ISO image found on Ubuntu's website

Comment: This is a good solution. It will be 10 times faster and should work.